# Test patterns for optical flow

Tags: opticalflow

We do a research on several optical flow implementations. The primary goal is to find, which one best fits our needs, and which parameter values work better than others. Now we do our tests on some self-made photos. But we're not sure if it's the best choice.

Are there any specific test images that can be used for this purpose, similar to test functions for optimization problems?

Comment: *The primary goal is to find, which one best fits our needs*. What are your needs?

Comment: We're trying to do facial morphing. We do an alignment using facial landmark detection, and then we calculate the displacements using Brox OpticalFlow implemented in OpenCV 3.1.0. But the resulting vector field does not seem to be precise enough, probably because of huge displacements and brightness variations between two frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of Optical Flow benchmarks where you can get samples. The most common are [Middlebury](http://vision.middlebury.edu/flow/), the [KITTI2012/2015](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow.php?benchmark=flow), [SIntel](http://sintel.is.tue.mpg.de) and the [HAMA](http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/motionAnnotation/) dataset/benchmarks. But most recent optical flow methods struggle with large motions, varying illumination and low contrast/textures.

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. Could you please name some of these recent methods? That is exactly what we are looking for

Comment: DeepFlow is one of the most recent, if you go to the KITTI homepage you will find a table that contains most of the recent flow techniques, some of the e.g. RLOF which I submitted, provides code too.

Comment: Thank you, Tobias. That's really helpful!